# Non-Normal empirical distribution sampling

Tags: distributions, sampling

I want to determine if some sampling I have done is significantly enriched or not compared to a null empirical distribution.I have collected data for the counts of genes in a certain sized window (80Kb). So in order to compare I have surveyed the genome 1000 times and also obtained the counts for each survey (1000 counts). Now when I plot the null empirical distribution I would expect it to be normal however there seems to be some effect giving me a shoulder on the left most side in the histograms and when I plot the qq plots it is also showing some bias for a lower number of counts.

[image: QQ Plot of Sample Data]

[image]

Originally I was going to take the "Normal" null-empirical distribution and determine the p-value of my original count to see if it was enriched or not. Now with these data I am not too sure about the best approach.

Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious problem I see is that there is quite a large number of 0s in your data. I would start with investigating those. Are these real 0s or did something go wrong during the measurement? How would you want to model those 0s? Are there special reasons that make it realistic that they happen, but do these reasons need to be part of your model? etc.

Comment: Hi Maarten, I too was thinking along the same lines and investigated this. It seems that some sampling occurred in centromeric regions whihc will result in 0 counts.

Answer (score 0):

As Maarten rightly pointed out there are a number of 0's in the data that were due to sampling from the centromic regions and hence there will be no measurement of this.
When I filter these regions out I then find a much better plot of the data.

[image]

Thanks for your help :)